# How to integrate spring with GWT?

Tags: java, spring, gwt

If I understand correctly, it's more efficient to use spring as a mediator for object persistence than using ibatis directly.

There seem to be a lot of libraries which ease spring integration by implementing a dispatcher for gwt rpc calls.

Would you recommend gwtrpc-spring or gwt-widgets?

Comment: Regarding the title, I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used gwt-widgets with both 1.5 and 1.6, and it works. Once you get the initial configuration done, all is fine.

I can't say anything about gwtrpc-spring, but still gwt-widgets seems to be the more mature project, with a larger community.